# module 'minisam' has no attribute 'DiagonalLoss'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv, eigen3

I am using [PyICP](https://github.com/gisbi-kim/PyICP-SLAM) github repo. I built the Sophus from this commit (commit a0fe89a323e20c42d3cecb590937eb7a06b8343a) [Reference](https://github.com/dongjing3309/minisam/issues/14).
I am using Ubuntu 22 and used virtual environment (venv with python version 3.7.14) to build the PyICP repo, minisam and Sophus repo.

Finally when I run the command  `python3 main_icp_slam.py` it runs in this error.

`(venv) shubham@shubhamubuntu:~/Lidar_Slam/minisam$ python3 main_icp_slam.py  Traceback (most recent call last): File "main_icp_slam.py", line 50, in <module> PGM = PoseGraphManager() File "/home/shubham/Lidar_Slam/minisam/utils/PoseGraphManager.py", line 9, in __init__ self.prior_cov = minisam.DiagonalLoss.Sigmas(np.array([1e-6, 1e-6, 1e-6, 1e-4, 1e-4, 1e-4]))  AttributeError: module 'minisam' has no attribute 'DiagonalLoss' (venv) shubham@shubhamubuntu:~/Lidar_Slam/minisam$ python3 main_icp_slam.py`  
The image view of this error is [HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z7fAzhnVr8bqBUPLxW4RmpZx3R1msS8p/view?usp=sharing)

I am not sure is it caused by Sophus, Eigen, Venv or minisam.

Let me know if anymore information is needed.

Thanks, for any and all the help.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you have multiple versions of python on your system and you have installed minisam on another python version. When you run cmake (for installing minisam) look at the version it shows for the python executable and also check your root python version (or environment that you are using), they should match.
If they don't match either make an environment with the python version your minisam is installed on or run your code as follows: (let say it is installed on python 3.6)

```
$ python3.6 main_icp_slam.py
```